# GROUP and COUNT() ages in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to group by date of birth and count based on the results, using  CakePHP. Here's my query.

```
$data = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age",
        'COUNT(id)'
    ),
    'group' => 'age'
));
```

So far, so good. The field `User.dob` is date of birth, it's a `DATETIME` field.

Thing is, it returns something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 9
                    [COUNT(id)] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 10
                    [COUNT(id)] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 11
                    [COUNT(id)] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 12
                    [COUNT(id)] => 8
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 13
                    [COUNT(id)] => 1
                )

        )
```

Surely there must be a better way.

And I can't even filter it. This code throws error. Unknown column 'age'

```
$data = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('age >' => 20),
    'fields' => array(
        "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age",
        'COUNT(id)'
    ),
    'group' => 'age'
));
```

By the way, these are the queries.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age, COUNT(id) FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY age
```

(The age calculation routine was found in [matt's blog](http://ma.tt/2003/12/calculate-age-in-mysql/).)

Answer (score 4):

The results you get are pretty much the best that CakePHP produces.

To simplify this you should use [Set::combine](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) which re-indexes your array.

You would need to call `$data = Set::combine($data, '{n}.0.age', '{n}.0.COUNT(id)');`

This would return an array with age as the index and count as the value:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(id)] => 1

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(id)] => 1

        )
    ...
)
```

The reason for the extra depth in the array is that cake uses the model as the key for the inner array if you are not using calculated fields, so that you can put in multiple models as fields and they will be split into different arrays. When you use calculated fields it keeps the same structure, but doesn't know the model so has to put it in a general array.

So lets say you want to group by male/female as well and you have a User.sex field, which is not a calculated field.

```
$data = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        "User.sex"
        "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age",
        'COUNT(User.id) AS [count]' // n.b. you have to give aliases normally
    ),
    'group' => 'age', 'User.sex'
));
```

This would return (something like):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [sex] => Male
                )
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 4
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [sex] => Female
                )
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 10
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [sex] => Male
                )
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 10
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

Thus for consistency the extra depth is always there even if you only use calculated fields

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that in set combine, make sure the first path is unique as it will be used at the key.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't think you need `'COUNT(id)'`. You can always count that in PHP easily:

```
foreach($data as $group){echo count($group);}
```

To filter, check on the original field, not the derived one:

```
'conditions'=>array('User.dob >' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-20 years')))
```

Anyhow, there's always `Model->query()` if you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting numeric indexes on your results array because the fields you are adding haven't been generated by CakePHP. CakePHP usually generates queries (and field names) more like this in SQL:

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`name` FROM `items` AS `Item` WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Item`.`name` ASC
```

You should try and mimic CakePHP's field naming conventions when adding custom elements to your queries, if you want CakePHP to better understand and format the results coming back from MySQL:

```
$age = "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(User.dob, '00-%m-%d'))";
$data = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.age >' => 20),
    'fields' => array(
        $age . ' AS `User`.`age`',
        'COUNT(id) AS `User`.`count`'
    ),
    'group' => 'User.age'
));
```

Maybe this will give you more luck getting the conditions to work. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried that. It keeps throwing syntax error in MySQL.

Comment: I would suggest trying out the new "virtual fields" feature in CakePHP 1.3.. although the code is 'beta' status, all the tests from 1.2 still pass: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/13-new-features-virtual-fields (upgrade instructions: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/13-migration-guide)

Comment: Seriously, I am irritated at cake's inability to do this, even in 1.3, virtual fields is on the model, that means you cant retrieve a count on a group by clause.

Comment: @Nightwolf The question asked does retrieve counts on a group by clause. The results aren't laid out perfectly, but see my answer using [Set::combine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1492/combine) for re-indexing the array as you want

Answer (score -1):

What version of cakephp are you using? I think earlier versions of 1.2 and I believe all versions of 1.1 had some issues with group by and complex aggregate queries -- it was later [resolved](http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/new-way-to-group-by-in-cakephp/). That said the results look like cake is running what you are asking it to: returning a list of the ages, and the count of the users with that age.

Regardless, why run that in mysql and tie up your db server? Get the raw values, and rewrite the query to calculate the aggregates in php, and append it to the returned array.

If you must use mysql, there is always $this->query(); For complex queries its often worth it to bypass cake, but as I said, the results make sense given the query.